# Can you use a PL-SQL procedure in JavaScript in a PL-SQL package?

Tags: javascript, ajax, plsql, oracle-apex, plsql-package

I want to create a button using JavaScript/ Apex, so that when I click on it, a PL-SQL procedure is being "called". Similar to a regular html button, but the onClick="JavaScript function()" will be a pl-sql procedure instead. I'm trying to do this in a PL-SQL package.

Is it even possible? If it is, I'd really appreciate a simple example of how it's done.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to call the procedure from JS? Otherwise just create a dynamic action of type execute PL/SQL code and call the procedure, set the dynamic action to be called on button clicked and voila, you're a wizard Harry

Answer (score 3):

As you tagged the question with the "oracle-apex" tag, then this is the situation:

- there's an (Oracle) Apex application
- it has a page
- you want to create a button on it and - when it is pressed - call a procedure (which is part of the package) (for example, `pkg_emp.p_employee(par_empno in number`))
- you want to involve JavaScript into it

No problem until the last statement. **Why** JavaScript? This is Apex. Once you created a button (let's call it `P1_BTN_EMP`), create a **process** :

- its type will be "PL/SQL Code"
- PL/SQL code will be

  ```
  pkg_emp.p_employee(:P1_EMPNO);
  ```

  where `:P1_EMPNO` represents a page item you're about to pass to the procedure
- under "Server-side condition", set "When button pressed" to `P1_BTN_EMP` (i.e. button name you previously created).

That's all.

If I completely missed the point, I apologize; and no, I don't know how to do what you explicitly stated, sorry.

Comment: I agree. This is the way it should be done unless you want to use Ajax for a specific reason. In that case, the comment from Damir is relevant because Dynamic Actions make this much easier than raw JavaScript.